# Microsoft Azure Custom Domains Check Fails on Custom Domain Add Operations

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

I have a custom domain that is registered with and managed by Microsoft Azure. I want to be able to access the domain with or without the "www" prefix.

When running the Troubleshoot function in Microsoft Azure for a Custom Domain, the check "Custom Domain Add Operations" always fails for the naked domain (i.e., without the "www" domain prefix).

In the details section, the naked domain URL is present, along with a Failure Reason of:

> A TXT record pointing from asuid..com to
>    was not found. Alternative CNAME record 
>   awverify..com to awverify..azurewebsites.net 
>   was not found either.

However, my DNS Zone for .com has an A record for the name "@" with a value of my Custom Domain's IP address. It also has a TXT record for the name "asuid" with the value "" and a CNAME record for the name "awverify" with the value "awverify..azurewebsites.net."

[image]

My site is currently operating as expected on Azure and is rendering the App Service correctly when accessing the custom domain with the "www" prefix.

Comment: Any update or is the issue fixed?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you [configure the domain purchase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#configure-the-domain-purchase) in the app service domain page. If you miss the steps to select the desired options for your domain with `www` or `@(root domain)` in **Assign default hostnames**, you can assign hostnames to the app refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain#assign-hostnames-to-app) in the same subscription.

To map an `A` record to an app, App Service requires two DNS records:

- An `A` record to map to the app's IP address.
- A `TXT` record to map to the app's default domain name `<app_name>.azurewebsites.net`. App Service uses this record only at configuration time, to verify that you own the custom domain. After your custom domain is validated and configured in App Service, you can delete this `TXT` record.

In this case, since you have been able to access the domain with or without the `www` prefix, you can remove the redundant TXT records named `@`and `asuid`, and CNAME record named `awverify`.

Let me know if you need further help on this issue.